# Why are my motors stuttering?

Tags: arduino, motor

Using my Arduino Uno, I have managed to arm my drone motors and keep them running continuously and stutter free. I have an esc between the motors and the arduino so I am using the Servo library.

```
<#include <Servo.h>

Servo motor1;
Servo motor2;
Servo motor3;
Servo motor4;

void armMotors(Servo motor1, Servo motor2, Servo motor3, Servo motor4){
  motor1.attach(3);
  motor2.attach(4);
  motor3.attach(5);
  motor4.attach(6);

  motor1.writeMicroseconds(2000);
  motor2.writeMicroseconds(2000);
  motor3.writeMicroseconds(2000);
  motor4.writeMicroseconds(2000);
  delay(1500);
  motor1.writeMicroseconds(1000);
  motor2.writeMicroseconds(1000);
  motor3.writeMicroseconds(1000);
  motor4.writeMicroseconds(1000);
}

void setup(){
  armMotors(motor1,motor2,motor3,motor4);
  delay(5000);
  motor1.writeMicroseconds(1090);
  motor2.writeMicroseconds(1090);
  motor3.writeMicroseconds(1090);
  motor4.writeMicroseconds(1090);
}

void loop(){
}
```

So I recently bought an arduino nano 33 ble. Same code and same wiring and the motor sound like they are studdering but still spinning. Every few seconds there is a little jump on one of the motors. I have tested them individually and the problem still occurs. I'm convinced its my new board and I want to know why and how to fix it. I appreciate all the help I can get.

[image: My setup]

Comment: Instead of going all in and hope that everything instantly works, why not turn off all motors except for one and debug that one? Break down the problems into smaller parts that you can troubleshoot and then say "okay, it can't be this, moving on"

Comment: Already tried that. Each motor has a studder even when I use different pins.

Comment: Something has changed. Look at every separately identifiable component (hard or soft) and see what is different. If nothing is different then you are doing something somewhere other than you think. || As you have chosen to give us nowhere enough information to compare the two systems you'll need to do this yourself. || You say " ... 33ble" -> that alone contains a host of possibiities. Was the old system using ble? If not what was it using and why did you not say? If both ble, are aerials, tx powers, tx & rx specs, BT code versions, interfaces, ... ? the same?

Comment: A decent block diagram showing any and all components involved may help us and you. Same "RX" at drone end? Known to work with the new BLE? Does eg a  resistor stutter (viewed eg on a scope) when driven with the new system. ...?

Comment: Just posted the circuit I used with both arduinos. The arduino uno is a 5v board while the nano 33 ble is a 3.3v board. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Is the time between 'shudders' regular or random? What happens if you set a different pulse width (eg. 1000, 1100, 1500)?  How are you powering the motors and ESCs? _"I'm convinced its my new board"_ - you might be right. Do you have any way to test the servo outputs independently of the ESCs (eg. servo, oscilloscope)? 3.3V vs 5V should not be a problem.

Comment: You've just made a *massive* change of platform.  From your description, it sounds as if you new platform is (perhaps unnecessarily) doing software PWM, or at least software-retriggered PWM and also dividing its time between your code and background tasks, which might be as simple as a timer interrupt and as complex as servicing the BLE radio.  At the very least, this shows how far you are from meaningfully building a "drone". You have likely chosen the wrong platform. If you really want to do this, get a known-flight-qualified open source hardware / software combination as a starting point.

Comment: Trying to build a flight controller on a novel platform all by yourself is perhaps a reasonable task once you have a solid practical understanding of existing systems, and a willingness to understand what is going on underneath the Arduino layer (or better yet, drop that and target the chip directly).  At present though, the problem you are stuck on is far simpler than "supposed to be hard" ones you'll face in getting this system to lift off in controlled flight.  Pick up a $20 "whoop" clone you can flash silverware on or something and get some practical experience of drone firmware.

Comment: It seems that something is wrong with the Servo.h library for me. Controlling the motors using the mbed class PwmOut makes the studder disappear.